# In docusign rest api, while creating envelopes it always send to the other mail except json contained mail?

Tags: java, docusignapi

The post request of creating envelop in `docusign` api.

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes

**Request Json Object:**

```
{
  "enableResponsiveChoice": true,
  "emailSubject": "Guuu",
  "envelopeId": "02c73303-704c-485d-b30f-c6cae3adfa6c",
  "autoNavigation": true,
  "status": "sent",
  "workflow": {
    "currentWorkflowStepId": "",
    "workflowSteps": []
  },
  "signingLocation": "online",
  "allowMarkup": false,
  "createdDateTime": "2019-05-28T06:31:03.150Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-05-28T06:31:03.150Z",
  "statusChangedDateTime": "2019-05-28T06:31:03.150Z",
  "expireEnabled": "true",
  "expireAfter": "120",
  "envelopeIdStamping": true,
  "signerCanSignOnMobile": "true",
  "isSignatureProviderEnvelope": true,
  "allowComments": true,
  "hasComments": false,
  "allowViewHistory": "true",
  "envelopeMetadata": {
    "allowAdvancedCorrect": "true",
    "enableSignWithNotary": "false",
    "allowCorrect": "true"
  },
  "envelopeLocation": "current_site",
  "isDynamicEnvelope": "true",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "name": "shailesh",
        "email": "shaileshbhurle1221@gmail.com",
        "recipientId": "6",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "xPosition": "150",
              "yPosition": "200",
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Response Object:**

```
{
    "envelopeId": "e88f7f69-34e0-4bfa-b6bf-ce443073f3d6",
    "uri": "/envelopes/e88f7f69-34e0-4bfa-b6bf-ce443073f3d6",
    "statusDateTime": "2019-05-28T19:51:53.0100000Z",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

It envelop wont sent to **shaileshbhurle1221@gmail.com** else it sent to other mail id. but why?

Answer (score 2):

In Request Json:
{
..
"envelopId":""
}
it means that envelope was already created, and email was locked for that particular envelop Id that why it send to the other mail id rather than XXXXXXXXXXX1221@gmail.com.

Comment: Correct. You should not set envelopeId in the Envelopes::create call. Thank you for integrating with DocuSign

Comment: Welcome! I have question for u how to secure DocuSign webhook url. In DocuSign document clearly stated that while calling webhook url they provide message body and header inside message body they will provide hash code of secret key of connect where I created. But still I am not getting any signature field in message body . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: please ask your question as a new question in StackOverflow.

Comment: Okay I asked please check it out once

Comment: Above question has any problem, I need clarification